# How to use getInitialProps in _app.js file with function component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I just see code _app.js file like this

```
class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    const { token } = parseCookies(ctx);
    
    return { pageProps };
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <Layout {...pageProps}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

This is _app.js file

```
function App({ pageProps, Component }) {
    
    return (
        <Layout >
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default App;
```

I want to convert first code examle to this. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set it up as follows, but be aware when you have `getInitialProps` on your app you are blocking *every* page, see more details here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

```
function App({ pageProps, Component }) {
    return (
        <Layout >
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
    )
}

App.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  // Logic goes here
}

export default App;
```